# bootstrap modal with select2 z-index

Tags: bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to load content from different html page to a popup then applying select2 on it.

everything is working, but the z-index for the select2 is not correct, event if I modified it to bigger value than bootstrap dialog is.

[image]

here is a snippet of what I'm doing

```
.select2-dropdown {  
  z-index: 10060 !important;/*1051;*/
}
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: You've tagged this with Select2 4.0.0, but your screenshot is definitely from an older version. What version of Select2 are you using?

Comment: No, I've referenced version 4.0 already ..., this was working on 3.5.x, but I've updated to ver 4.0 and un-reference the old version

Comment: Have you checked this doc: https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems. Seems like select2 v4 have a know issue with bootstrap modal

Comment: @CassioSeffrin, thanks a million!

Answer (score 37):

Combining a couple solutions found on the Select2 GitHub issue tracker seems to get Select2 v4 working with Bootstrap modals.

Add this css...

```
.select2-container--open {
    z-index: 9999999
}
```

Then I was still unable to type in the search box... removing the "tabindex" attribute from the modal div fixed that.

Answer (score 22):

In fact, you shouldn't mess with the Select2 z-index.

You should define the modal in which the select2 is rendered, just like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#s2id_autogen5").select2({ 
        dropdownParent: $("#myModal") 
    }); 
});
```

Assuming your modal id is "myModal" (it's not readable on your image).

This will avoid the z-index effect while also avoid other colateral effects of messing with the z-index (like rendering the select2's search field unreachable).

Comment: I did that and it brings forward, but the list is behind the modal.

Comment: Hi there @GuilhermeFlores. Do you have any other css affecting Z-Order of the select2 or any of it's inner elements? If so, just disable it all, and be sure that the "dropdownParent" value is pointed do the bootstrap's modal container.

Answer (score 4):

I hope its work

Try to remove `tabindex="-1"` from modal.

Comment: It worked for me, I was runing into troubles with this, I know that tab will not close the modal but, is better than can't write anything in the select2 sarch box.

Answer (score 2):

Add custom css with `modal-open` class

```
.modal-open .select2-container {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap v5 and select2 v4 I did  this

```
  .select2-container--open {
            z-index: 9999999;
        }
```

and *focus: false*

```
let modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(myModalEl, { focus: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I did use this solution

style="z-index: 50 !important;" directly on the modal

```html
<div id="mdl_name_id" class="modal " tabindex="-1"  style="z-index: 50 !important;" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks messy, for me both of these required:

```
.modal{
    z-index: 100000 !important;
}

.select2-container--open {
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
}
```