# Django Autocomplete Light not working with Bootstrap 5 Modal

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-5, django-autocomplete-light

I am newbie to Python and Django.

I'm using DAL on a form inside a Bootstrap modal. Clicking the dropdown list appears behind the modal.  The autocomplete function works correctly if I do it outside of the modal.

I'm using:

Django: 4.0.5

django-autocomplete-light: 3.9.4

Bootstrap 5.2.2

Python 3.10.4

To try to fix it, I have created a style.css file with the following code, as indicated in:
[bootstrap modal with select2 z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620292/bootstrap-modal-with-select2-z-index)

```
.select2-container {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Now the list appears in front of the modal, but it doesn't allow typing in the search box. I've tried doing the following, but it doesn't work:

https://select2.org/troubleshooting/common-problems

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#codigo_emplazamiento").select2({
      dropdownParent: $("#FormularioCrear")
    });
  });
```

I've tried removing `tabindex="-1"` from the modal, but it doesn't work.

It seems to be related to this, but I can't get it to work:
https://lightrun.com/answers/yourlabs-django-autocomplete-light-search-input-not-receiving-focus

This is my code:

**forms.py**

```
class FormularioTarea(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tarea
        fields = ['referencia_interna', 'codigo_emplazamiento', 'estado', 'fecha_fin', 'tipo_documento']
autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='emplazamientoautocompletar')})
        widgets = {
            'codigo_emplazamiento': autocomplete.Select2(
                url='emplazamientoautocompletar',
                )
    }
```

**models.py**

```
class Emplazamiento(models.Model):
    TIPO_ELECCION = (('URB', 'Urbano'), ('RUR', 'Rural'))
    codigo_emplazamiento = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    municipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipio, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ref_catastral = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True)
    tipo_emplazamiento = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=TIPO_ELECCION)
    latitud = models.DecimalField( blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=10, max_digits=13)
    longitud = models.DecimalField( blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=10, max_digits=13)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.codigo_emplazamiento = self.codigo_emplazamiento.upper()
        return super(Emplazamiento, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        ordering =('-id',)
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.codigo_emplazamiento)


class Tarea(models.Model):
    referencia_interna = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    codigo_comparticion = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    ESTADOS_DE_TAREA = (('PENDIENTE', 'Pendiente'), ('EN_CURSO', 'En Curso'), ('FINALIZADO', 'Finalizado'))
    codigo_emplazamiento = models.ForeignKey(Emplazamiento, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=ESTADOS_DE_TAREA)
    SELECCION_DE_DOCUMENTOS = (('PROYECTO', 'Proyecto'), ('ANEXO', 'Anexo'), ('PEP', 'Pep'))
    tipo_documento = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=SELECCION_DE_DOCUMENTOS)
    fecha_entrada = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    fecha_fin = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering =('-id',)
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.referencia_interna + ' - ' + str(self.id))
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('emplazamientos/autocompletar', EmplazamientoAutocomplete.as_view(), name = 'emplazamientoautocompletar'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class EmplazamientoAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        #if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
         #   return Country.objects.none()
        qs = Emplazamiento.objects.all()
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(codigo_emplazamiento__icontains=self.q)
        return qs
```

**Modal in Template:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="FormularioCrear" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">{{ titulocreador }}</h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="CuerpoModal">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" {% url 'creatarea' %}">
          {% csrf_token %}

          {{ formulario.as_p }}

        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#codigo_emplazamiento").select2({
      dropdownParent: $("#FormularioCrear")
    });
  });
  
  </script>
```

**Modal in rendered template:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="FormularioCrear" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Crea nueva Tarea</h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="CuerpoModal">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" /proyectos/tareas/crear/">
          <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="kWogOGY57TUQv49PCR5CroMbEmpMiM5qNUC17gTI6gPZjrq3riiuiXrhm2STNuTk">

          <p>
    <label for="id_referencia_interna">Referencia interna:</label>
    <input type="text" name="referencia_interna" maxlength="20" required id="id_referencia_interna">
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_codigo_emplazamiento">Codigo emplazamiento:</label>
    <select name="codigo_emplazamiento" required id="id_codigo_emplazamiento" data-autocomplete-light-url="/proyectos/emplazamientos/autocompletar" data-autocomplete-light-function="select2" data-autocomplete-light-language="es">
</select>
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_estado">Estado:</label>
    <select name="estado" required id="id_estado">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="PENDIENTE">Pendiente</option>

  <option value="EN_CURSO">En Curso</option>

  <option value="FINALIZADO">Finalizado</option>

</select>
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_fecha_fin">Fecha fin:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fecha_fin" id="id_fecha_fin">
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_tipo_documento">Tipo documento:</label>
    <select name="tipo_documento" required id="id_tipo_documento">
  <option value="" selected>---------</option>

  <option value="PROYECTO">Proyecto</option>

  <option value="ANEXO">Anexo</option>

  <option value="PEP">Pep</option>

</select>
    
    
      
    
  </p>

        </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#codigo_emplazamiento").select2({
      dropdownParent: $("#FormularioCrear")
    });
  });
  
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is modal focus, so if you review the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/#options in options there's a definition for the focus. So at the end you just need to add data-bs-focus="false" to your modal definition.

...

Comment: Works! `.select2-container {z-index: 1056 !important;}` sends the dropdown list to the front and `data-bs-focus="false"` in the modal definition, allows the pointer to be entered into the text box. Both necessary. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Set the dropdownParent in **forms.py**:

```
"codigo_emplazamiento": autocomplete.ModelSelect2(
    url="emplazamientoautocompletar",
    attrs={
        "style": "width:50%;",
        "data-dropdown-parent": "#FormularioCrear",
    },
)
```

Remove the select2 instantiation from your template and allow DAL to handle instantiation for you. Delete the following:

```
$("#codigo_emplazamiento").select2({
    dropdownParent: $("#FormularioCrear")
});
```